# Reportviewer C# com parâmetros usando MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2013, reportviewer

Estou começando a desenvolver relatórios no Visual Studio 2013, utilizando C# com MySQL. No momento, consegui fazer um relatório sem parâmetros, porém, quando insiro parâmetros na consulta, ele retorna um erro.

A consulta que coloco no `dataset` é a seguinte

```
SELECT        celular, codigo, cpf, dt_nascimento, email, nome, observacao, rg, sexo, telefone
FROM            tb_clientes
WHERE        nome like '%' + @p_nome + '%';
```

Sem a cláusula `WHERE`,  o relatório executa normalmente.

Vi um exemplo na *internet* usando esta forma de passagem de parâmetro, porém, o banco de dados era o SQL Server.

Comment: Poste o código C# assim a gente vai saber melhor como os parâmetros estão sendo passados para o MySQL

Comment: Olá, ainda não tem nenhum código para passagem do parâmetro no relatório, somente esta consulta diretamente no reportview com o paramento @p_nome já esta dando erro. O erro da exatamente p_nome, parece que a consulta feita no mysql não aceita este parâmetro.

Comment: Você criou a variável @p_nome?

Comment: Então você vai ter que usar `SET @p_nome = 'alguma coisa'` pra poder testar o código diretamente no MYSQL sem passar os parâmetros pelo C#. Veja sobre query parametrizada.

Comment: sim o parametro @p_nome foi criado no menu do reportviewer, só que quando informo o parametro na consulta, parece que o mysql não entende, tentei fazer o SET @ p_nome que o Eduardo auxiliou, realmente funciona diretamente no MySQL, porém quando informo no dataset ele da erro na query, parece que não reconhece o parametro, ou não reconhece o como inicio de um parametro.

Comment: Coloca o link pro exemplo com SQL Server?!

Comment: Estou sem o sql server agora no computador para mandar, porém somente colocando o parametro @nome_parametro, já daria certo dentro do like no banco de dados. Estou mandando o link da consulta que coloco no sql server com o parametro, porém no mysql não funciona, gostaria de saber se tem algum exemplo para o mysql.Segue o link da consulta do relatorio no reportviewer usando sql server. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7125864/Imagem.jpg